# Oracle SQL - Calculating days passed by different user IDs

Tags: sql, oracle

I desperately need some help from your brains to solve one SQL problem I have now.

I have a very simple table made of two columns: Client # and Purchasing Date.

I want to add one more column to show how many days have passed since the previous Purchasing Date per each Client #. Below is my current query to create the starting table.

```
select client_id, purchasing_date
from sales.data
```

The result looks like this (apparently, I need more reputation to post images):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHUFa.jpg

[image: screenshot]

The highlighted column on the right is the column I want to create.
Basically, that shows the number of days elapsed since the previous purchasing date of each Client #. For the first purchase of each Client, it will be just 0.

I'm not sure if I have explained enough to help you guys produce solutions - if you have any questions, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: which sql database?

Comment: it's oracle thanks!

Comment: To improve your questions, consider [not posting images at all](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select client_id, purchasing_date,
       (purchasing_date -
        lag(purchasing_date, 1, purchasing_date) over (partition by client_id
                                                       order by purchasing_date
                                                      )
       ) as day_diff
from sales.data
```

Comment: by the way, i had to delete purchasing_date in that lag parenthesis to make it work.

Comment: @SanK, the third parameter is the optional default value to be returned if there is no prior record. If you don't supply it, the default is `NULL` which would cause `day_diff` to be `NULL` instead of zero (`0`).